# display FITS file content

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, fits

I have a bunch of data in of FITS file format that a I need to visualize.

Some details:

- I use *python* with *astropy* to manipulate and preview the data;
- The data stored in the FITS file is basically a numpy array with 70 lines ("orders") of 8096 pixels each (an *echelle spectrum*)
- the data is saved as a multipage pdf where each page corresponds to one specific order of the FITS observations
- I want to display the data as per figure 1:

  - figure 1 corresponds to one single order from each FITS file;
  - the "grey" region on the top panel corresponds to regions with no data/observations;
  - each "line"  on the top panel corresponds to a different observation (x-axis: wavelenght, y-axis: date of observation; z-axis: flux)
  - the red line is optional
  - the bottom panel is the same data as above, but with all obsevations overlapping (x-axis: wavelenght, y-axis: flux)
  - the flux is normalised to the median on the panels, but the fits will have values sometimes well above 10^7

now, I am facing the following problem. If I save in pdf (or even png, etc), I am limited by the dpi which I use. The higher the dpi, the better I can preview the data, but it becomes impossible to work with due to the file size. But with a low dpi, the data appears blurry. When I do a preview of the data with *matplotlib's* show, I can zoom in and out with no problems, but it becomes impossible to work with as I generate my images on a serve at work and it becomes impossible to do remotely.

So, my question is: is there a file format I could use to store my data similarly to figure 1 (ideally a multipage format and that I could use python to create, but not limited to.), but would allow me to work with an "infinite" resolution similarly to what I have with *matplotlib*'s show? There are several FITS file viewers "in the wild", but to my knowledge they do not allow to preview the data as I wish....

[image: Figure 1:]

Comment: 70*8096 = not a lot. One would think that a PNG of that resolution, embedded in a PDF and stretched appropriately, would not hurt performance. I can't help you to create one, though, but maybe someone else can help with that.

Comment: Hi Thomas, sorry, that would be OK if each FITS was displayed on one image. However, the PDF will consist of 70 pages, each page with two panels, where each panel will have at least 100 spectra (in the end I might have several hundreds) of 8096 pixels. And the main issue is the resolution, at low dpi it's easily manageable, but at high-dpi (300+), that would allow me to zoom in it becomes unmanageable. Ideally, I'd be looking at some kind stand-alone of container that I could configure to display the data as I wish in an interactive way...

Comment: I don't fully understand why you're outputting the images as a PDF. But *if* I understand correctly, it's so that you can view the data as it's processed on your server? Perhaps in the long term what you might need is a web-based FITS viewer like [Aladin lite](https://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/), either running on the same server as the one doing the processing, or at least on a server with access to the files on the other one (i.e. using a file share). That might end up being the most effective way to browse the outputs of your data processing but might be a pain to set up 

Comment: Did you find a container solution for your problem?